# What did Luke need power converters for?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Luke [famously](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/9/93/episode_vii.png) wants to go to Tosche Station to get some [power converters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Power_converter/Legends) rather than doing his job or helping his family.

**What did he need them for?**

Comment: Possibly his T-16? I think the only non-farming activities he had that would require a component like this was flying. Maybe his land speeder but that seemed to be in fine working order. I have a voice in the back of my head saying this might have had more detail in the novel.

Comment: Anyone who says "to convert power" will suffer my wrath,

Comment: @ToddWilcox - He also runs a landspeeder. It's *probably* one of those, but I'd like more proof than just probably.

Comment: Because he was a whiny git!

Comment: A search of the novel for the phrase "power converter" only turns up the line in question in the exact same scene.

Comment: @TGnat - Hence why everyone calls him "Wormy".

Comment: @Richard "Wormie", actually. (Novel search - it was right there in my hand)

Comment: To convert power?

Comment: According to Wookieepedia, a power converter is also used in blasters and other hand weapons, along with star ships, so it could have been for his rifle thing or even possibly his macrobinoculars.

Comment: he was going to trade them in for one quarter portion.  Oh, wait....

Comment: the T-16 skyhopper or his speeder mayhaps?

Comment: This is pure speculation, but since Owen assumes he's just going to waste time with his friends, maybe the power converters are just an excuse to go to the station. Perhaps they're used in moisture farming, so Luke thought he could get out of doing work by pretending to do other work.

Comment: The power converter in his uncle's coffee maker was faulty, and a fire hazard, so Luke needed to replace it.

Comment: I'm going to go with: "George Lucas wanted to throw in some technobabble that sounds spacey and futuristic (long-long-pasteristic?)"

Comment: @MikeClark - But he must have had *something* in mind.

Comment: Because he's a schmuck.

Comment: Hmm. Having just put a chunky bounty on this, I've then found an answer. Crap.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpUkokRx3-k

Comment: For the record, I posted my smartass comment before I saw Richard's warning about smartass comments.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29641752#29641752

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well , the real reason is given in the film:

### He wanted an excuse to slack off and play hooky with his friends

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

> LUKE:  But I was going into Toshi Station  to pick up some power
>   converters...
>
> OWEN:  You can waste time with your  friends when your chores are 
>   done. Now, come on, get to it!

Why did this seem like a plausible excuse, though? Luke must have had something he needed power converters for.

### Power converters may be necessary for moisture farming

> “Moisture farming. Spectacularly dull. Some weeks were so boring that
>   I actually looked forward to going into Tosche Station to pick up
>   some … power converters. Huh!”
>
> “What?”
>
> “I just remembered I never did pick up my last shipment. Wonder if
>   they’re still there.”
>
> —*Heir to the Jedi*

This seems to indicate that power converters were necessary for something that Luke did regularly, with the implication that it's a chore related to moisture farming.

In this case, perhaps the converters are for the [moisture vaporators](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

> A light wind whips at him as he adjusts several valves on a 
>                  large battered **moisture vaporator** which sticks out of the 
>                  desert floor much like an oil pipe with valves.

Legends [provides further evidence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756614198) that the power converters are necessary for the operation of the moisture farm:

[image]

The text says: **Owen Lars emerges from storage area with replacement parts for power converters.**

It is possible that the converters are for the vaporators in this case, but it is also possible that they are for the step-down transformer (also circled).

Either way, the fact that Owen is carrying them makes it likely that their purpose is for moisture farming, not powering vehicles, droids, or weapons.

<sup><sub>Thanks to Richard for suggesting this last one.</sub></sup>

Comment: On a desert planet with two suns solar power would seem like a valid energy choice. If moisture evaporators used AC and the solar energy system generated DC, then they'd need power converters to hook them together.

Comment: @Xantec - It's possible, I suppose.

Comment: That Heir to the Jedi quote is pretty good, now that I've read the whole answer. Not really proof, but still. +1

Comment: In the working world this is the, *Oh, we need a part? I'll go shopping on my (soon to be 3 hour) lunch break* trope.

Answer (score 1):

Luke didn't want to do his chores. That is the reaction most teenagers have to being told no. Luke would go get the converters, but then wind up spending time screwing around with his friends. also something kids do in a galaxy, *far far away*